# How to observe changes in system preference "Sidebar icon size" in AppKit?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

In the Main section of the System Preferences of macOS, the user can change the "**Sidebar icon size**". This setting changes the icon size (and since macOS 11 also the font size) used in Sidebars, when the size mode of the `NSOutlineView` in question is set to `default`.

I want to add an `UserNotification` observer in my app to track changes to the said setting, so I can perform some additional finetuning after each size change, but could not find any applicable `NSNotification.Name` or other constant.

Any workable solution or suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew I had a solution for this, but I was searching in the wrong projects. This is what I found. Observing `UserDefaults` is not a fantastic option, but at least it works:

```
fileprivate let tableViewDefaultSizeModeKey = "NSTableViewDefaultSizeMode"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: tableViewDefaultSizeModeKey, options: .new, context: nil)
}

deinit {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: tableViewDefaultSizeModeKey)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == tableViewDefaultSizeModeKey {
        // Do whatever is needed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code.
Please note that the changed value accessible in `observeValue(forKeyPath...` is the reliable way to access the new value. If one tries to access the effectiveRowSizeStyle in the table/outline view in this callback, the value has not yet been set in the view..and is still equal to the old value.

I also tried to call reloadData() from the `observeValue(forKeyPath...` callback to force a redraw of some cells that had some custom icon sizes, and found that event in the drawing code, the new updated rowSize was inaccessible. I ended up adding a custom ivar to my OutlineView to store the 'next' rowSize in order to properly size my icons in the redraw of the cells.